# php condition not working

Tags: php

I am trying to hide a URL on the site based on the condition that the result of the query is either blank or is equal to upload/ but I can't seem to make it work.

I basically have a MySQL table that has a field called file, now one the user submit the form, the file field is not required but it will save the "upload/" on the database. For example, if I submit the form twice, one with a file attachment and the 2nd one without an attachment, my table will look like this:

```
fileID   |  filename
1        |  upload/file1.txt
2        |  upload/
```

Now, on my page, I only want it to display the result if there is a file uploaded but I can't seem to make it work. Here is what I've tried:

```
if ($filename = "upload/" ) {
   echo "No file uploaded";
} else {
  echo "<div class='span2' style='padding-left:10px;'><a href='".$filename."'>Download Attachment</a></div>";
}
```

But it echo'es out "No file uploaded" regardless if I have a file uploaded or not.

Comment: thanks for all the replies, i think I might be sleepier than I thought to have missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use equality operator `==` instead of `=`

```
if ($filename == "upload/" ) {
 echo "No file uploaded";
}else {
  echo "<div class='span2' style='padding-left:10px;'><a href='".$filename."'>Download Attachment</a></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using an assignment operator instead of an equality operator.

Change the first line to:

```
if ($filename == "upload/" ) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing an assignment.

```
if ($filename = "upload/" )
```

basically translates to "Set the value of $filename to 'upload' and then check if it has a value.  Of course it always will have a value at that point and therefore return true.

You need to be using the comparison operation

```
if ($filename == "upload/" )
```

Problems like this crop up all too easily due to = and == being so similar.  Some programmers follow the convention of putting the value that can't change (Constants, literals, function calls, etc) on the left so that if they accidentally type = instead of == the program will error out instead of exhibiting the kind of behaviour you're observing, making finding such errors a lot easier.

```
if ('upload/' == $filename)
```

If you accidentally write

```
if ('upload/' = $filename)
```

then PHP will try to assign a new value to a constant.  This will obviously fail and your PHP script will terminate with a fatal error telling exactly where the error occurred.  Finding and fixing it then becomes pretty easy.